# Volume generated by revolving region of $y=-1,y=\ln x,x=y^2+1$ about $y=1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

I am trying to find the volume of solid generated by revolving region of $y=-1,y=\ln x,x=y^2+1$ about $y=1$ using shell method.
here is the picture.
[image]

I need help in setting up the integral?
I actually figured out that
$$V=2\pi\int_{-1}^{0}(1-y)(y^2+1-e^y)dy$$
But i am not sure?

Comment: Yes for shell method, the integral is set up correctly